# Cómo aplastar los botones en pantalla, conectándolos al Arduino?

Tags: python, tkinter, botón, arduino, pyserial

Hola chicos estoy trabajando en este código:

```
import tkinter as tk
import serial
arduino = serial.Serial('COM3',9600) 

def funcion():
    print("boton presionado")
    
ws = tk.Tk()
ws.title("proyecto")
ws.geometry("300x350")
ws.config(bg = "grey")
#--------------------------
mi_canvas = tk.Canvas(ws, height=300, width=300)
mi_canvas.pack()

#----------------
boton = tk.Button(ws, text = "Boton", height = 3, width = 14, bd = 4,command=funcion)
boton.place(x=0,y=300) 
boton2 = tk.Button(ws, text = "Boton", height = 3, width = 14, bd = 4,command=funcion)
boton2.place(x=150,y=300) 
#--------------------------
ws.mainloop()
```

Mi pregunta es como hacer para aplastar los botones que se muestra en pantalla, conectando dos botones al Arduino

Answer (score 1, accepted):

comparto el código en Arduino para la lectura de los dos botones usando los pines 2 y 3, y con un tiempo de retardo en la lectura de 100 ms. Son parámetros que se pueden modificar. De acuerdo al botón que se presione, se envía por el puerto serie una cadena para identificar cual botón se presionó.

```arduino
const int buttonPin1 = 2;
const int buttonPin2 = 3;

int buttonState1 = 0;
int buttonState2 = 0;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(buttonPin1, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(buttonPin2, INPUT_PULLUP);
}

void loop() {
  buttonState1 = digitalRead(buttonPin1);
  buttonState2 = digitalRead(buttonPin2);

  if (buttonState1 == LOW) {
    Serial.println("boton1");
  }

  if (buttonState2 == LOW) {
    Serial.println("boton2");
  }

  delay(100);
}
```

El código en Python modificado, contiene un hilo de ejecución para la lectura del puerto serie. Con la función `invoke()` se presiona el botón.

```python
import threading
import tkinter as tk
import serial
arduino = serial.Serial('COM3',9600) 

leer = True

def funcion():
    print("boton presionado")

def cerrar_ventana():
    global leer
    leer = False
    ws.destroy()
    
def leer_arduino():
    while leer:
        if arduino.in_waiting > 0:
            botonPresionado = arduino.readline().decode()[:-1].strip()
            if botonPresionado == 'boton1':
                boton.invoke()
            elif botonPresionado == 'boton2':
                boton2.invoke()  

ws = tk.Tk()
ws.title("proyecto")
ws.geometry("300x350")
ws.config(bg = "grey")

ws.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", cerrar_ventana)
#--------------------------
mi_canvas = tk.Canvas(ws, height=300, width=300)
mi_canvas.pack()

#----------------
boton = tk.Button(ws, text = "Boton", height = 3, width = 14, bd = 4,command=funcion)
boton.place(x=0,y=300) 
boton2 = tk.Button(ws, text = "Boton", height = 3, width = 14, bd = 4,command=funcion)
boton2.place(x=150,y=300) 
#--------------------------

thread = threading.Thread(target=leer_arduino)
thread.start()

ws.mainloop()
```

Espero sea de ayuda.

Comment: Esta seccion `while True: if leer == False: break` hace lo mismo que `while leer`